# How to resolve the situation that malloc() corrupts the pointer?

Tags: c, memory, pointers, malloc, corruption

Here's a simplified version of a function I wrote just now:

```
int foobar(char * foo) {
  puts(type);
  struct node * ptr = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof(struct node));
  puts(type);
  memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr));
  ptr=head;
  return head->id;
}
```

Here `node` is just a struct declared as a node in the linklist, which contains a `char *` and a pointer to the next node. However, I realize that the `malloc()` here is corrupting my input `char * foo`.

Why would `malloc()` corrupt my input char pointer? Also, how could I resolve the issue here? Now I am just copying the content of that pointer to a local array, but this is too hacky, even for my taste (which isn't the best).

Thanks for any inputs!

EDIT: Well, here's more real code:

```
void foobar(char * type) {
  puts(type); <-- here it's a long string about 30 char
  struct node * ptr = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof(struct node));
  puts(type); <- chopped of, 10 left with some random thing at the end
}
```

Hope the problem is clear now! Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's how `type` got initialized:

```
type = strdup("Some ");
tempType = strdup("things");
sprintf(type + strlen(type), "%s", tempType);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where does `type` come from?  Is that the local array you constructed to store `foo`?  Did your original code have calls to `puts(foo);` before you added `type`?

Comment: You should not be casting the return value from `malloc(3)`, as including the `stdlib.h` header will provide a prototype and thus the compiler will be able to perform type checking for you -- when you cast the return value, you might be papering over a warning that can indicate incorrect code.

Comment: Why do you think `malloc` is the culprit?  We don't have enough information to come to this conclusion nor to answer the question.

Comment: @AaronDufour: The char pointer is fine before the malloc(), but corrupted after the malloc(). I tried to print it and it showed so, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei In the first code block the argument is `foo` but `type` is printed.  It makes more sense now.  Can you show us how the block of memory pointed to by `type` is initialized?  That's probably the important bit.

Comment: @AaronDufour: Edited one more time. Thank you for the advices!

Comment: @ZiyaoWei Yep that made the problem clear.  See Jonathan's edited answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The apparent corruption would happen because `type` or `foo` points at already freed memory which `malloc()` gives back to you for a different use.

Once you've released the memory, you cannot continue to use it.

You also have a problem because you allocate to `ptr`, then wipe `ptr` out with:

```
ptr = head;
```

You might have meant:

```
head = ptr;
```

but you would probably need to set `ptr->next = head;` before that.  Of course, this is speculation since you've not shown the type definitions.

It also isn't obvious why you return `head->id` instead of either `head` or `ptr`.  Unfortunately, we don't have enough information to say "that *is* wrong"; it is just not usual.

---

#### Commentary on 2nd Edit

> Here's how type got initialized:

```
type = strdup("Some ");
tempType = strdup("things");
sprintf(type + strlen(type), "%s", tempType);
```

There is some of the trouble.  You've gone trampling on memory that you have no business trampling on.

The first two lines are fine; you duplicate a string.  Note, though, that `type` is a pointer to 6 bytes of memory, and `tempType` is a pointer to 7 bytes of memory.

The disaster strikes in the third line.

`type + strlen(type)` is pointing to the null byte at the end of the `type` string. You then write 1 byte of `tempType` over it more or less legitimately; you don't have a null terminated string any more, but the first byte is within bounds.  The second and subsequent bytes are written in space that is not allocated to you, and that probably contains control information about memory allocation.

Writing out of the bounds of the allocated memory leads to 'undefined behaviour'.  Anything can happen.  On some machines, particularly with a 64-bit compilation, you might get away with it altogether.  On most machines, and especially 32-bit compilations, you've wrecked your heap memory and something somewhere (typically somewhat distant from this spot) will run into trouble because of it.  That is the nature of memory abuse; the place where it occurs often appears to work and it is some other innocent piece of code that suffers from the problems caused elsewhere.

So, if you want to concatenate those strings, you need to do something like:

```
char *type = strdup("Some ");
char *tempType = strdup("things");
char *concat = malloc(strlen(type) + strlen(tempType) + 1);
sprintf(concat, "%s%s", type, tempType);
```

I've omitted error checking.  You should check the allocations from `strdup()` and `malloc()` to ensure that you got memory allocated.  Some might argue that you should use `snprintf()`; it was a conscious decision not to do so since I've calculated the necessary space in the previous line and allocated sufficient space.  But you should at least consider it.  If you have not ensured that there is enough space available, then you should use `snprintf()` to avoid buffer overflows.  You would also check its return value so you know whether the information was all formatted or not.  (Also note that you have 3 pointers to free, or pass off to some other code so that the allocated memory is freed at an appropriate time.)

Note that on Windows, `snprintf()` (or `_snprintf()`) does not behave the way specified by the C99 standard.  Frankly, that's not helpful.

Comment: can you explain how it happens? doesn't sounds rational char* foo is on the stack and malloc is on the heap. thanks

Comment: We can't see where the trouble is; it isn't in the code shown.  But a standard way to get 'corruption' when data is allocated is to have a pointer that points at freed memory.  Another way to cause trouble is to free a pointer that was on actually not allocated via `malloc()` but was pointing to the stack or even the static data areas of your program (`.data` and `.bss` segments); more usually though, that leads to a core dump than just corruption.

Comment: This was just somewhat simplified for this question here. I'll try to edit it to better show my question.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei: It's always a tricky business knowing how much to remove from a bigger program to present a problem like this.  The ideal is a program of about 10-40 lines that still reproduces the problem.  It would be unusual to be able to get it smaller than 10 lines; you don't want to go very much bigger, though sometimes it is necessary.

Comment: Edited. Thanks! I didn't quite predict that just these would cause a problem, but the main function is just calling this with a long char string.

Comment: Edited again. I am not sure if this reveals anything? And I don't know if this is useful, but I am generating the main program using Bison, and it's a part of a school project so I don't/can't upload it all. Thanks!

Comment: That's awesome! I learned a lot from your post. I gotta show this around to my confused friends who have been tricked by me into believing that this code is legitimate. Seriously, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but the comments indicate what's happening:

```
// This allocates enough memory for a struct node and assigns it to ptr.
struct node * ptr = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof(struct node));

// This displays the data in the (unspecified) string type,
// which must be null terminated.
puts(type);

// This sets the first 4 bytes of ptr to 0, assuming pointers are 4 bytes.
// You probably want memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(struct node));
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr));

// This makes ptr point to the address of head, orphaning the memory
// that was just malloc'ed to ptr.
ptr=head;
```

Comment: +1 for observing that the `memset()` is setting the wrong amount of space.

Comment: I believe `sizeof(*ptr)` would be correct, as well as far clearer.

Comment: Edited my question, and I hope now the problem is clear. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronDufour:  It might be worthwhile to write a small program to test your belief.  Then post the result if you don't mind.  Right or wrong,  we'll all learn something!

Comment: @AdamLiss I created a 40-byte `struct node`, and declared `struct node *ptr;`.  The results for `sizeof(struct node)`, `sizeof(*ptr)`, and `sizeof(ptr)` were `40`,`40`, and `8`.  So, it looks like my assumption was correct.

Comment: @AaronDufour +1  Thank you for investigating and following up!